# AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'regularizers'

Tags: python, keras

I try to run a Python project from Git for the first time. After having installed all needed librariers I started the program and I received following error:

**AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'regularizers'**

Source:

```
from keras import layers, models, optimizers
from keras import backend as K

class Actor:
    '''
    Actor(policy) Model
    '''
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size

        self.build_model()
    
    def build_model(self):
        states = layers.Input(shape=(self.state_size, ), name='states')

        net = layers.Dense(units=16, kernel_regularizer=layers.regularizers.l2(1e-6))(states)
        net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
        net = layers.Activation('relu')(net)
        net = layers.Dense(units=32, kernel_regularizer=layers.regularizers.l2(1e-6))(net)
        net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
        net = layers.Activation('relu')(net)

        actions = layers.Dense(units=self.action_size, activation='softmax', name='actions')(net)

        self.model = models.Model(inputs=states, outputs=actions)

        action_gradients = layers.Input(shape=(self.action_size, ))
        loss = K.mean(-action_gradients * actions)

        optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=.0001)
        updates_op = optimizer.get_updates(params=self.model.trainable_weights, loss=loss)
        self.train_fn = K.function(
            inputs = [self.model.input, action_gradients, K.learning_phase()],
            outputs = [],
            updates = updates_op
        )
```

Comment: from keras import regularizers

Comment: sometimes a "fix" can be so easy - solved the issue. Thanks Marco!

Answer (score 0):

I think the program was written in TensorFlow version 1 and also keras version 1. You may be solved the problem by writing that way
       `net = layers.Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=tensorflow.keras.regularizers.L1(1e-6))(states)`
but will occur so many errors. As there used some functionality that has been removed in later versions such as

```
optimizer.get_updates
```

no longer works. So, better work with later version